# Interval that runs periodically forever

Tags: rx-java

Ok, usually one could use `Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` to create an observable that will emit a value every second.

But `interval` emits an integer value. What will happens if we let this run until ÌNT_MAX`? An overflow?

Is there an operator that could do the same, i.e. periodically emitting a value without a counter.

Basically I just want an Observable to schedule a periodically job ... kind of ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `interval` emits a `Long` value and internally uses a `long` counter. You will never hit `Long.MAX_VALUE` in practice (emitting one value per nanosecond it will take 292 years to overflow).

Answer (score 0):

`interval` returns `Observable<Long>`. So the value emmited by counter is long.

If we let this run until LONG_MAX, Overflow will be happened. But `interval` will not stop.
`interval` will continue emitting values like this:

- 9223372036854775807
- -9223372036854775808
- -9223372036854775807

If you want `interval` without a counter, create `OnSubscribe` like this:

```
public class OnSubscribeNoCounterTimerPeriodically  implements Observable.OnSubscribe<Void> {
    final long initialDelay;
    final long period;
    final TimeUnit unit;
    final Scheduler scheduler;

    public OnSubscribeNoCounterTimerPeriodically(long period, TimeUnit unit) {
        this(period, period, unit, Schedulers.computation());
    }

    public OnSubscribeNoCounterTimerPeriodically(long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler) {
        this.initialDelay = initialDelay;
        this.period = period;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public void call(final Subscriber<? super Void> child) {
        final Scheduler.Worker worker = scheduler.createWorker();
        child.add(worker);
        worker.schedulePeriodically(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                try {
                    child.onNext(null);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    try {
                        worker.unsubscribe();
                    } finally {
                        Exceptions.throwOrReport(e, child);
                    }
                }
            }

        }, initialDelay, period, unit);
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
Observable.create(new OnSubscribeNoCounterTimerPeriodically(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

Comment: You won't be able to reach Long.MAX_VALUE in practice. The number is too big.

Comment: I think so too. I just answer the question.